# Minimum of $\frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{x+z}-\frac{1}{x+y+z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $0\leq x,y,z\leq 1$. What is the minimum of $$F(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{x+z}-\frac{1}{x+y+z}?$$

We have $F(1,1,1)=2/3$, $F(1,1,0)=F(1,0,1)=F(1,0,0)=1$, and $F(0,1,1)=3/2$.
Is the minimum $2/3$?

Comment: I think you're confusing quite some things here. First, why do you assume that the minimum lies on the boundary? Second, a Google-search on multivariable calculus may help. There's a method to do this and it's not especially hard.

Comment: @Steven I didn't assume that the minimum lies on the boundary -- I just checked some values on the boundary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in an elementary way.

Consider the last two terms, which contain $z$ - they sum to $$\frac y{(x+z)(x+y+z)}$$

Increasing $z$ clearly decreases this term, so for a minimum you want $z$ as large as possible - changing $z$ doesn't change the first term at all. You can do a similar analysis for $y$. So with the constraints you have $y=z=1$

$$F(x,1,1)=\frac 2{x+1}-\frac 1{x+2}=\frac 1{x+1}+\frac 1{(x+1)(x+2)}$$

This is the sum of two positive terms which decrease with increasing $x$ (in the range you have) so the minimum is when $x=1$.